# Me aparece este error, Python, Tkinter : IndexError: string index out of range - Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

espero alguien me pueda orientar, estoy usando un "Treeview y el bind" (""), uso el evento clik para mandar a una función, me aparece error, lo que me tiene confuso es que a veces aparece el error y a vece no aparece, es aleatorio según creo, he leído respuesta parecida a mi consulta pero no consigo el error o la solición, si alguen me puede orientar, se lo agradeceria.

Aqui esta mi código, este el el primer Treeview

```
    # Comienza el Treeview
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.windows_historia, height = 8, columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', 
    '#6', '#07', '#08', '#09', '#10', '#11'), show="headings")
    self.tree.place(x =20, y = 180)

    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self.windows_historia, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
    vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

    self.tree.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0)
    self.tree.column("#1", width=150, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#2", width=150, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#3", width=150, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#4", width=90, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#5", width=90, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#6", width=80, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#7", width=100, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#8", width=100, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#9", width=90, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#10", width=150, minwidth=50)
    self.tree.column("#11", width=10, minwidth=10)


    self.tree.heading('#0', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text = '1er Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text = '2do Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#4', text = 'F Registro', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#5', text = 'F Nacimiento', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#6', text = 'Tipo', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#7', text = 'Señas', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#8', text = 'Profesión', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#9', text = 'Telefonos', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#10', text = 'Correos', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#11', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
    
    self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.seleccionarusandoclik)
    self.tree.bind("<Button-1>", self.seleccionarusandoclik)
    self.get_pacientes()
```

Aqui esta el segundo Treeview

```
    # Comienza el Segundo Treeview
    self.tree1 = ttk.Treeview(self.windows_leer_imagen, height = 5, columns = ('#1', '#2', '#3', '#4', '#5', '#6'), show="headings")
    self.tree1.place(x =100, y = 150)

    vsb1 = ttk.Scrollbar(self.windows_leer_imagen, orient="vertical", command=self.tree1.yview)
    vsb1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

    self.tree1.column("#0", width=0, minwidth=0)
    self.tree1.column("#1", width=0, minwidth=0)
    self.tree1.column("#2", width=0, minwidth=0)
    self.tree1.column("#3", width=90, minwidth=10)
    self.tree1.column("#4", width=400, minwidth=400)
    self.tree1.column("#5", width=90, minwidth=30)

    self.tree1.heading('#0', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('#1', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('#2', text = '', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('#3', text = 'Fecha', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('#4', text = 'Descripción de la imagen', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.heading('#5', text = 'Tipo de Imagen', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree1.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb1.set)
    self.tree1.bind("<Double-1>", self.seleccionarusandoclik1)
    self.tree1.bind("<Button-1>", self.seleccionarusandoclik1)
    self.get_fotos_pacientes()

# Consulta
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result
    #return [rec for rec in result]
```

Aqui se genera en error en cualquiera de los dos funciones, pero es aleatorio no siempre da error

```
def seleccionarusandoclik(self, event):
    item2 = self.tree.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
    self.miid_paciente=(self.tree.item(item2, 'text'))
    self.minombre.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[0])
    self.miapellido1.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[1])
    self.miapellido2.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[2])
    self.mifecha_registro.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[3])
    self.mifecha_nacimiento.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[4])
    self.mitipo.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[5])
    self.misenas.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[6])
    self.miprofesion.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[7])
    self.mitelefonos.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[8])
    self.micorreo.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[9])
    self.miobservacion.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[10])
    self.calcular_anos()
    self.tipo_paciente()
```

Segunda función

```
def seleccionarusandoclik1(self, event):
    item1 = self.tree1.identify('item', event.x, event.y)
    self.miid_visual=(self.tree1.item(item1, 'text'))
    self.miid_nombre_imagen=(self.tree1.item(item1, 'value')[1])
    self.midescripcion_imagen.set(self.tree1.item(item1, 'value')[3])
```

Aqui relleno el primer Treeview

```
# Función de relleno del Treeview
def get_pacientes(self):
    #Limpiando la Tabla
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    #consultando lo datos
    query = 'SELECT * FROM paciente'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[0], value=row[1:12])
```

Aqui relleno el segundo

```
# Función de relleno del Treeview
def get_fotos_pacientes(self):
    #Limpiando la Tabla
    records = self.tree1.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree1.delete(element)
    #consultando lo datos
    self.fecha_actual=''
    parameters=(str(self.miid_paciente), )
    query = "SELECT * FROM Visuales WHERE ID_PACIENTE_VISUAL = ? ORDER BY datetime(FECHA_VISUAL) DESC" 
    db_rows = self.run_query(query, parameters)
    #Rellenando los Datos
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree1.insert('', 0, text = row[0], value=row[1:6])
```

Este es el error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line  1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 573, in seleccionarusandoclik
    self.minombre.set(self.tree.item(item2, 'value')[0])
IndexError: string index out of range

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Oftica\oftalmenu.py", line 592, in seleccionarusandoclik1
    self.miid_nombre_imagen=(self.tree1.item(item1, 'value')[1])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

A veces aparece en el [0], a veces en el [1], a veces en el [9], es aleatorio
Si alguien tiene idea de mi error, por favor, se lo agradeceria, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Estuve viendo tu código, y no encuentro ningún error en él. Para mi el error tiene relación con la forma de ingresar los datos de la base de datos a los treeviews. Podrías agregar el código donde llenas a los treeviews con información por favor?

Comment: Si, ya agrego las dos funciones

Comment: No encuentro ningún error en tu código. Incluso probé hacer un treeview y rellenarlo del mismo modo que haces vos y no encontré nada extraño. Lamento no poder ayudar...

Comment: Muchas gracias, he estado leyendo y buscando porque presenta el error aleatorio por no doy con la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes controlar las excepciones...

```
def tvItems_event_select(event):
    item_fields_data_clear()
    try:
        item_id = tvItems.selection()[0]
        item_fields_data_get(item_id)
    except IndexError:
        #print('debe seleccionar un elemento...')
        pass

tvItems.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', tvItems_event_select)
```

Referencia: https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions